# "Undeclared variable" declaration in python

Tags: python

The following code is an example:

```
class A(object):
    def f(self):
        pass
A.f.b = 42
```

How is this variable being allocated? If I declare A.f.a, A.f.b, and A.f.c variables am I creating 3 different objects of A? Can someone explain what's going on in memory (as this does not appear to be something easily coded in C)?

Comment: have you tested this code ? you cannot add a member to a function. But you could do `A.b = 42`, which would add a class variable to `A`.

Comment: Yes, you can. You are adding attributes to the bound function `f`.

Comment: @IanAuld: would seem like it could work but not like this: `    A.f.b = 42
AttributeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute 'b'`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre The attribute error is thrown in Python 2, but Python 3 allows binding new members like so

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre (1) what version of python are you running it under? (2) You obviously understood the intent of the question when you stated A.b = 42. Would you happen to know the answer?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye: yes python 2 on this machine (work machine). Home machine has python 3: leads me to mixups.

Comment: @chepner  Is there a contradiction between you and Jean-François Fabre's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following only works in Python 3:

```
class A(object):
    def f(self):
        pass
A.f.a = 41
A.f.b = 42
A.f.c = 43
```

`A.f` is an object of type `function`, and you have always been able to add new attributes to a `function` object. No instances of `A` have been created; the three attributes are referenced from the function `f` itself.

If you had two instances `a1 = A()` and `a2 = A()`, however, neither `a1.f.b` and `a2.f.b` are defined, because `a1.f` is not a reference to `A.f`; it is a reference to an object of type `method`. This results from how Python's descriptor protocol is used to implement instance methods.

Answer (score 0):

`A.b = 42` adds a class variable to `A`, and thus makes it visible instantly for each instance of `A` (but only 1 entry in memory)

You can add attributes to classes and instances anytime you like in Python. The cleanest way would be to do it a declare time or this could be misleading.

```
class A:
    b = 12
```

But for quick "extensions" of classes or instances you could choose to dynamically add them.

ex:

```
class A(object):
    pass

a = A()
print('b' in dir(a))  # False
A.b = 42
print('b' in dir(a))  # True even if instanciated before creation of `b`
```